# Orchard Content Manager: how to apply an OR operator between different Part Records fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I need to filter data using an OR operator on fields from two different parts:

```
var result = ContentManager.Query("ContentType")
.Where<PartARecord, PartBRecord>(
  (a, b) => a.FieldA.Contains(searchText) || b.FieldB.Contains(searchText)
).List();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You might want to switch to an Hql query. Except that FieldA and FieldB better actually be properties of the records, not Orchard fields. Except that using Contains is a sure way to kill your perf. Why not just use full-text search?

Comment: OK, I will give HQL query a try. Would be nice to have a way of referencing fields from multiple part records using ANDs and ORs with the content manager.
The .contains is just an example, I actually need to do a more complex filtering. Thanks for your help!

Comment: HqlQuery *is* a method on ContentManager, so your wish is granted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Fields values stories in database as Infoset and you can't query it by standard sql (IHqlQuery or IContentQuery). But if you enable Projection Part that Fields values will be also story in separate table and you will be able to query this.

You can try something like this (I'm not sure that it will be work. May be have to replace Any() or Contains() functions)

```
var result = ContentManager.Query("ContentType")
    .Where<FieldIndexPartRecord>(p => p.StringFieldIndexRecords.Any(
        f =>
            (f.PropertyName == "ContentType.FieldA." && f.Value.Contains(searchText)) ||
            (f.PropertyName == "ContentType.FieldB." && f.Value.Contains(searchText))
        ))
    .List();
```

But if you will use IHqlQuery, that do

```
var result = ContentManager.HqlQuery().ForType(new string[] { "ContentType" })
    .Where(
        a => a.ContentPartRecord<FieldIndexPartRecord>().Property("StringFieldIndexRecords", "fieldAAndB"),
        f => f.Or(
            f1 => f1.And(
                checkName => checkName.Eq("PropertyName", "ContentType.FieldA."),
                checkValue => checkValue.Like("Value", searchText, HqlMatchMode.Anywhere)
            ),
            f2 => f2.And(
                checkName => checkName.Eq("PropertyName", "ContentType.FieldB."),
                checkValue => checkValue.Like("Value", searchText, HqlMatchMode.Anywhere)
            ))
        )
    .List();
```